# Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem - contradiction with a limit?

Tags: limits

Consider the function given by $$f(x)=x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $$f(0)=0.$$

As this function is differentiable for every $x\in\Bbb R$, we can use Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem: For every $x\in\Bbb R$, there is a $\delta_x\in]0,x[$ such that
$$x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}=x(2\delta_x \sin\frac{1}{\delta_x}-\cos \frac{1}{\delta_x})$$ whereas 
$$\cos\frac{1}{\delta_x}=2\delta_x \sin\left(\frac{1}{\delta_x}\right)-x\sin\frac{1}{x}$$ Now as $x$ tends to $0$, $\delta_x$ also tends to $0$. Passing to the limit, we obtain $$\lim_{x \to 0}\cos\frac{1}{\delta_x}=0,$$ whereas it is known that $$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\cos\frac{1}{\delta}$$ does not exist.

**My question.** Where is the mistake in my argumentation?

Comment: $0$ is one of the limit points of $\cos \frac{1}{x}$ when $x\to 0$, this is not a contradiction.

Comment: +1 for raising a fine point.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read it a little bit different

You know, that $\forall_{x > 0} \exists_{\delta(x) \in (0,x)} $, such that $ \cos(\frac{1}{\delta(x)}) = 2\delta(x)\sin(\frac{1}{\delta(x)}) - x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) $

Now, as you pointed out, while $x\to 0^+$, then because $\delta(x) \in (0,x) $, then $\delta(x) \to 0^+$, too.

There exists a limit of RHS and is equal to $0$ as you claim. But that doesn't mean that there exists $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos(\frac{1}{x}) $. We only know, that for a sequence $\{ x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ tending to $0$, there exists a sequence $\{ \delta(x_n) \}_{n \in \mathbb N }$ tending to $0$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} cos(\frac{1}{\delta(x_n)}) = 0$

Comment: But what if $\delta_{x}$ takes on all intermediate values in the neighbourhood of $0$

Answer (score 1):

Your $ \delta$ depends on $x$ ! $\delta=\delta(x)$.

Your argumentation shows that $\lim_{x \to 0}\cos\frac{1}{\delta(x)}=0$.

But this does not mean that $\lim_{t \to 0}\cos\frac{1}{t}$ exists !